# Can application size be limited after installation?

Tags: java, android, performance

After installing application on a testing device, the size of app increases as I use it daily. But I would like to limit my application size, let's say up to 100mb. Means new data must overwrite old data when app size reaches to 100 mb, i.e. app size must not exceed 100mb anyways.

Comment: See this https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size

Comment: you can do it only manually checking current size when you want to write data, and choosing whether you need to delete some data before writing new

Comment: Do you mean *total app size* increases (apk + cache + data)? Which part increases as you use it?

Comment: yes @rustyx , i want to limit the size of my app i.e(apk + cache + data). data part increases very fast .

Comment: So are you asking how to measure the data size? The apk is how you programmed it, and won't change. The cache is something the OS will clear itself when it grows too big. Overwriting your data is something nobody can help you with (it's your data and you didn't tell us anything about them).  So all you need to know is to measure the data size, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, altough it would be a little harder, as you'd have to do 2 things simultaneously:

> 1. Learn the exact app size after installation
> 2. Constantly monitor and control the app cache and storage

You may have noticed already, that the .apk or .aab (bundle) size is far less than the actual size of the app after it's installed on the device. But you can use `org.reflection` API and `PackageManager` to get it with a few lines of code at runtime:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms", new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
        throws RemoteException {

        Log.i(TAG, "Size of the installed app: " + pStats.codeSize);
    }
});
```

This would be the code you'd want to run just after the installation, and save the value, as you'll use it later to calculate the size on the disk by combining it with other cache you have.

Secondly, each time you are going to persist something - either using `SharedPreferences`, a database (`SQLite`) or saving to a file, you'd have to count the bytes of the data saved, and calculate the sum of the saved data and the app size after installation.

Also, I'd suggest a best way to go for precision is be to **save everything to a file, and avoid using databases and `SharedPreferences`**, as it's much easier and consistent to get the exact file size. As your file size + the app size after installation > 100mb, you can tell the user, that he cannot save any more data, and has to free some space, etc.

I hope you got the idea..

Answer (score 0):

**Can we Limit our application size after installation?**- NO

App size is one of the biggest factors that can affect your app’s install and uninstall metrics, so it’s important to regularly monitor and understand how you can reduce your app’s download and install sizes. Since the two sizes are related, here’s how they’re different from each other:

- **Download size:** The size of your app that users download on Google
  Play. When an app has a larger download size, it takes longer to
  download.
- **Size on device (at install time):** The amount of space required to
  install your app. Since apps are compressed when they’re downloaded,
  it can make install sizes larger than download sizes. When an app has
  a larger install size, more space is required on a user’s device to
  complete installation. After the app is opened, its size on disk
  varies depending on app usage.

Comment: I don't think the OP meant the download size or the installation size, but rather the user data generated by the app over time which is said to increase with daily use.